# Написать функцию, реализующую RSS на сайте

Tags: php, rss

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм как на PHP написать функцию, реализующую RSS на сайте?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну почему же не погуглить?? [A Simple PHP Class to Create RSS Feed](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/simple-rss-class-create-rss-feed)

---

Ну вот примерно так: [Create an RSS feed with PHP](http://www.carronmedia.com/create-an-rss-feed-with-php/)

Comment: да потому что погуглить и быстро найти ответ на этот вопрос намного быстрее, чем ждать от кого-то ответа

Comment: Спасибо, но нужна функция, а не класс.

Comment: О_о но почему именно функция и что Вы вкладываете в это понятие?

Comment: вообще, RSS это обычный XML файл, почитайте его структуру и напишите сами :)